# How to manage all metadata in a single file in Next.js 13?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, seo, metadata

i want to manage all metadata in a single file called "metadataConfig.js" file.

metadataConfig.js file will look like this

```
export const medataDataConfig = [
  {
    about: {
      title: "Title Text...",
      description: "Description Text...",
    },
  },
  {
    services: {
      title: "Title Text...",
      description: "Description Text...",
    },
  },

  {
    contact: {
      title: "Title Text...",
      description: "Description Text...",
    },
  },
];
```

now when someone will visit about route then it will get metadata from here dynamically.

now i just want to add metadata from here dynamically for every route in my app.

In "next.js" docs described metadata only work in server side components. so in server side i can not use "usePathname" hook to check where im now so i can not filter the data for this specific route.

**Is there a way to do this in a best practice and SEO friendly way?**

Comment: Why not have the `metadata` on each page unless you are using a dynamic segment (aka the `[id]` folder)?

Comment: I just want to manage all the metadata in one file so I can easily edit or add new ones in a single place